# Refresh a specific div in page after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have 2 pages chat.php and allchat.php and I can successfully load allchat.php page in chat.php div after 10 seconds
Here is a code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function() {
            $("#abc").load("allchat.php");
        }, 10000);
    });
```

Now If I have a div having id "def" in chat.php and How I do to refresh this div after 10 second. Remember I don't load any otherpage like in above code
I try this code but It is not working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function() {
            $("#abc").load("chat.php #def");
        }, 10000);
    });
```

Comment: not working?? gives error on console??

Comment: What is in chat.php?

Comment: No. It refersh the whole page. not only abc div

Comment: Chat.php is the page where we have a div abc. and I need to refersh this div after 10 seconds

Comment: (Chat.php is the page where we have a div abc) .. Chat.php should have div #def not #abc  ... is it a bad typo? or you really mean you want to load the same page which you want to load it?

Comment: I am sorry for writing abc instead of def. Actually I load div def.

Answer (score 0):

Just like for the div `abc` you created a separate page i.e. `allChat.php` similarly for the div `def` you should also create a separate page say `def.php` then after 10 sec load this page in exactly same way.

Comment: Yeah I know that but Why I cant refresh def div which is on page

Comment: If that portion is supposed to be loaded again and again it is better to keep it in a separate file. That will make a good practice. Also you don't have to load the full page, just the portion only

Comment: Actually I revieve 2 values on chat.php page using get method. and If I make a new page then I need these 2 values on that new page